# Удаленное парное программирование с помощью tmux/wemux

Tags: linux

Добрый день.

Возникла необходимость организовать совместную работу с кодом для двух удаленных unix-вых машин. Многие мануалы советуют использовать старый-добрый tmux, в предпоследнем Radio T'е же был представлен усовершенствованный wemux с тем же, по существу, функционалом. Установил обе софтины, после чего возник вопрос - как, собственно, могу создать сервер/подключиться к удаленному, не имея статического IP?

Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос в том, как узнать адрес? Пусть кронтабом через curl или wget дёргает какой-нибудь файлик, который будет вести логи адресов, с которых его запросили. По этим логам можно узнавать динамические адреса. А есть ещё сервисы типа no-ip

Comment: no-ip заюзал в итоге